# PostgreSQL RETURN NEXT error "returned more than one row"

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3

I have a long drawn out PGPLSQL function :here is a summary

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_features_by_buffer(
                    p_buffer GEOMETRY
                )
RETURNS SETOF JSON AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        v_buffer GEOMETRY;
        v_sql TEXT
    BEGIN
    FOR REC IN EXECUTE $$(
                (
                    SELECT row_to_json(foo_pole) AS json FROM 
                       (
                         SELECT * FROM pole WHERE $$ || v_sql_where || $$
                       ) AS foo_pole
                 )
                 UNION ALL 
                 (
                    SELECT row_to_json(foo_transformerbank) AS json FROM 
                       (
                         SELECT * FROM transformerbank WHERE $$ || v_sql_where || $$) AS foo_transformerbank
                       )
                 )$$ LOOP
        RETURN NEXT REC.json;
    END LOOP;
    END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My function returns `RETURNS SETOF JSON` and its a bit more complicated than shown here, however I have run the queries that are inside the `UNION ALL` statement and there is no syntax or other error. It looks weird here because I've been tinkering but I originally tried it by putting the query statement in `v_sql` and doing `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_sql`, that also gives the same error as the version show here. The error is as follows:

> ERROR:  query "SELECT get_features_by_buffer(v_buffer)" returned more than one row
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_features_by_pole_distance(character varying,double precision) line 7 at RETURN NEXT

I have been tinkering with this for a while, not sure what I'm missing here, something to do with the `UNION ALL`?

Comment: looks strange. Probably fragment of code is not related to this bug. If you need returns more than one row once, you should to use `RETURN QUERY` command.

Comment: I agree with Pavel. A loop seems unnecessary. Just use `return query` - or even better: use a SQL function instead and get rid of the PL/pgSQL overhead

Comment: Sorry, I wan't clear. This is inside a function. I have tried `RETURN QUERY`and the only way I can get it wo work is to assign a variable, `v_sql` to the query statement then run `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_sql` I'll a bit more context in the post.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you don't need the cursor. Just use the generated SQL as the input to `return query execute ...`:

It's also easier to generate dynamic SQL using the `format()` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_features_by_buffer(p_buffer GEOMETRY)
   RETURNS SETOF JSON 
AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_buffer GEOMETRY;
    v_sql TEXT
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
    format(
      'SELECT row_to_json(foo_pole) AS json 
      FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM pole 
        WHERE %s
      ) AS foo_pole
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT row_to_json(foo_transformerbank) AS json 
      FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM transformerbank 
        WHERE %s
      ) AS foo_transformerbank', v_sql_where, v_sql_where);
 END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As that function is declared as `returns setof` you have to use it like a table:

```
select * 
from get_features_by_buffer(...);
```